# Select partial columns from table and joined table Criteria API

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to select 2 columns from different tables (they are joined), but I can't manage to make it work using Criteria API.
The problem is, I've created a DTO class as a Projection, but I can't convert the joined table entity to the inner class. To clarify, here are my classes:

User:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users", indexes = {@Index(columnList = "email", unique = true)})
    public class User extends BaseEntity {

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String firstName;

        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
        private Set<Role> roles;
```

Role:

```
@Table(name = "roles")
@Entity
public class Role extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;
```

The DTO class:

```
public class UserRoleDto {
    private String email;
    private Set<RoleDto> roles;

    public UserRoleDto(String email, Set<RoleDto> roles) {
        this.email = email;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Set<RoleDto> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<RoleDto> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public static class RoleDto {
        private String name;

        public RoleDto(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, what I've tried:

```
    @Override
    public Optional<UserRoleDto> findByIdWithRoles(UUID id) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<UserRoleDto> query = builder.createQuery(UserRoleDto.class);

        Root<User> root = query.from(User.class);
        root.fetch("roles", JoinType.LEFT);

        query.where(builder.equal(root.get("id"), id));
        query.select(builder.construct(UserRoleDto.class, root.get("email"), root.join("roles")));

        UserRoleDto user = entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();

        return Optional.ofNullable(user);
    }
```

As you can see, I'd like to query only the user.firstName and from the Role joined table the name. How do I convert from Role to UserRoleDto.RoleDto here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work. You can only use the JPA constructor syntax for creating objects from scalar results, but not for nested structures. You would have to build the object graph yourself.

Anyway, this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

Blaze-Persitence is a query builder on top of JPA which supports many of the advanced DBMS features on top of the JPA model. I created Entity Views on top of it to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model. Since the attribute name is used as default mapping, you mostly don't need explicit mappings as 80% of the use cases is to have DTOs that are a subset of the entity model.

A mapping for your model could look as simple as the following

```
@EntityView(User.class)
interface UserRoleDto {
    String getEmail();
    Set<RoleDto> getRoles();
}

@EntityView(Role.class)
interface RoleDto {
    String getName();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`UserRoleDto dto = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, UserRoleDto.class, id);`

But the Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

It will only fetch the mappings that you tell it to fetch